# How to Auto Upload a json file to my github Website

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, github-pages

There is a program in my company that generates a JSON file. I created a website (that will be live on github pages) using java script and html that displays the information from this JSON. Now I want others in my company to generate individual JSON files and be able to upload them to this website by clicking a single button. I'm thinking the button they click would generate the JSON (let's say it saves automatically as c:data.json), programmatically open the github pages website and then programmatically upload c:data.json. I do not want the json file to be stored on the website, just uploaded for one time use.

I have done a couple google searches and can only seem to find stuff on how to upload a json file in your code which I am already doing locally. I need a local file to programmatically upload, in order to be used in a github pages website. I'm new to web dev and any help is appreciated :)

OS: Windows 10
developed using: node.js, javascript, html, json, github pages.

[image: how I am currently uploading a sample json:]

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? I need the same. There are some custom media types for blob. I can't understand how to use it.